# Adicionar "thead" à uma tabela criada com createElement

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte código, que cria uma tabela, utilizando `createElement()`:

```js
var context = document.createElement('table');
var row; context.className = 'table';

row = context.insertRow();
row.insertCell().innerHTML = 'foo';
row.insertCell().innerHTML = 'bar';
```

Ao inspecionar o elemento, percebi que ele cria `<tbody>`, mas não o `<thead>`.

### Pergunta

Como fazer para adicionar o `<thead>` e seus elementos `<th>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode usar assim:

```js
var header = context.createTHead();
var row = header.insertRow();
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/s9V8v/)

Com jQuery é mais simples visto que é permitido criar elementos directamente e adicionà-los á tabela

```
var header = $('<thead></thead>');
var row = $('<tr></tr>');
var th = $('<th></th>').html('Cabeça');
row.append(th);
header.append(row);
context.append(header);
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/TYhJj/)

---

Se quiser inserir muitas linhas/colunas com javascript simples, aqui fica [**um exemplo**](http://jsfiddle.net/M49SH/) para adicionar várias linhas e colunas:

```js
var context = document.createElement('table');
context.className = 'table';
var header = context.createTHead();
var row = header.insertRow();


for (var i = 0; i < colunas; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement('th');
    th.innerHTML = 'Coluna ' + i;
    row.appendChild(th);
};

var body = context.appendChild(document.createElement('tbody'))
for (var i = 0; i < linhas; i++) {
    var row;
    row = body.insertRow();
    for (var j = 0; j < colunas; j++) {
        row.insertCell().innerHTML = 'foo';
    };
};

context.appendChild(body);
document.body.appendChild(context);
```

Comment: Eu utilizo um `jQuery.each()` para popular a tabela com dados vindos por `Ajax`.

Comment: @CalebeOliveira, adicionei info sobre como fazer com jQuery. Se postar aqui o seu código posso adaptar a resposta melhor

Comment: No meu caso, javascript simples é mais visualmente limpo. Está bom assim.